# cannot give strong or retain property to protocol object

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I've the following line of code

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<MessageItemProtocol> *message;
```

Here, i am getting an error : "property with 'retain' (or strong) attribute must be of object type "

I know that i am getting an error because it's a protocol. so, then what should be it's property type then ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<MessageItemProtocol> message;
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject<MessageItemProtocol> *message;
```

Comment: Tried the first one it worked, although what's the difference in the two ways that you have described here

Comment: `id` is a pointer to an object of any type. `NSObject*` is a pointer to an object of type NSObject or a subclass (pretty much every Cocoa class except a few exceptions).

Answer (score 3):

`id` already is a pointer, so you do not need `*`.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<MessageItemProtocol> message;
```